# Give an Example of diffeomorphism from unit circle to plane without circle.

Tags: calculus

> Give an Example of diffeomorphism from  circle to plane without
>   circle.

Any Ideas?

Comment: There are points on $x^2+y^2=1$ having one of $x,y$ zero. at these 4 points, your map is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try $(x,y) \to (1/(x+101),1/(y+101))
.$ Then each coordinate of image is positive and at most $1/100$ so image strictly inside unit circle.

Added: A much simpler map is $(x,y) \to (rx,ry)$ where $r$ is positive and not $1.$ That maps the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$ to the concentric (distinct) circle $x^2+y^2=r^2.$